# I want to give different colors to functions in 3D Plotting,

Tags: plotting

I want to give different colors to functions in a 3D plot. For example, in the following statement, what must be included for doing so?

```
Plot3D[{(y^2/x), (x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

Comment: Have you looked up `PlotStyle`?

Answer (score 2):

As Michael E2 said in his comment, the `PlotStyle` can be used to specify colors for each surface. Like so:

```
Plot3D[{(y^2/x), (x^2 + y^2)}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image: plot]